# Trying to import large sql file with BigDump and Mamp Pro

Tags: mysql

I have Mamp pro and I'm trying to import a sql file that is 388mb big. I was having issues doing this in PHPMyadmin so I was attempted to use BigDump ver 0.35. When I attempt to import the file I get an 
error:
[image]

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Christina, you'd be more likely to get help if you were respectful of the help others have provided you by marking answers to your questions as correct when the solution is provided.

Comment: Hey RobM has anyone responded to the question though ? I'm sorry if I'm missing something here